# Change click function from <tr> to <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make html page like a book library. In this user can click rate button so that selected book is saved to localstorage and they get the book rating whenever opening that page.

But the problem is this: when the user click the book name to read (i.e entire tr, if we click anywhere in tr) then it is getting rated without clicking on star button specifically.

How to make it rate only when we click on td which has star button.
. I am a newbie to jquery.I got below code from stackoverflow.
can anyone post complete jquery code so that I can Learn the difference in two codes.

I am posting the entire code Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        img {
            height: 25px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
        .ratingTable { width: 400px; }
        td {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        td[data-id] { width: 300px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 [<a href="comics.html">Comics</a>] [<a href="allbooks.html">All books</a>]<hr/>
    <table class="ratingTable">
        <tbody id="adventure">
            <tr>
                <td data-id="Book A">Adventure 1</td>
                <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-dais</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="fav">
                        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
                        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-id="Book B">Adventure 2</td>
                <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="fav">
                        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
                        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-id="Book C">Adventure 3</td>
                <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="fav">
                        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
                        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>    const showFavs = function(key,favs) {
      if (!favs) return;
      key = key.replace("favs",""); 
      favs = JSON.parse(favs);
      $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
        const selector = "#"+key+" tr td[data-id='" + fav + "']";
        $(selector).closest("tr").trigger("click"); // click the TR
      });
    };

    $(function() {
      $('tr').click(function(e) {
        const $parentTable = $(this).closest("tbody");
        $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
        $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
        const $favs = $("tr",$parentTable).has('img.yellow-star:visible');
        const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i, fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
 //       localStorage.setItem($parentTable.attr("id") + "favs", JSON.stringify(favs));   // Uncomment this on your server
      })

      // read all favs and trigger them

      Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
         if (key.endsWith("favs")) showFavs(key,localStorage.getItem(key));
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the following approach: add "AdRate" dummy class in <div class"fav">. So it will become <div class"fav AdRate">.. Than change   " $('tr').click(function(e) { " to " $('.AdRate').click(function(e) { "

Comment: @Khurram Ishaque  But when refreshing it rate disappears.I think we should make changes somewhere too not only here.Like the place of retrieving data from localstorage. please help me

Comment: the " localStorage.setItem(.... " line is commented in code. It might be the reason data is not stored !

Comment: @Khurram Ishaque   so sir i uncomment it . but still not working.

Comment: @DavidBeckam Why is binding the click event on dedicated td not an option?

Comment: An additional sidequestion: What is the usecase of `[]` surrounding the anchor tags ab the begin?

Comment: @Reporter  that is just prefix& suffix to the name saving to localstorage

Comment: @Reporter can you show me the code how to bind it with td

Comment: Add an answer.  Hopes it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I read the question several times, I wondered about following words

> But the problem is this: when the user click the book name to read
>   (i.e entire tr, if we click anywhere in tr) then it is getting rated
>   without clicking on star button specifically.
>
> How to make it rate only when we click on td which has star button.

Try following way.

1. Modify your html a little bit, by adding a dummy css to the table column withe rating icons:

> ```
> <td class="myratingSystem">
> ...
> </td>
> ```

Because there are no css declerations are defined, the browser does nothing to these tags. I use it quite often to focus on a particular element.

2. Modify your jquery script:

> ```
> $(function() {
>       $('td.myratingSystem').click(function(e) {
>         //As is written into question the rest of the code snippet here is working 
>         //as expected.
>         ...
>       });
> }
> ```

Also you have to change following lines:

> $(selector).closest("tr").trigger("click");

to

> $(selector).parent().find("td.myratingSystem").trigger("click");

Hope it helps.

Comment: I formated my code snippet as comment, because formating as code seems not working.

Comment: but when reshreshing rating doesn't retrieve from localstorage sir .please check that

Comment: May you should comment in the last line within the click event, so the broweser is able to store data. And check the browser console for errors. My test with js fiddle getting no errors (I checked only the logic fir click event).

Comment: By the way I oversaw another place to modify. Sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Sir, I tried latest method too. but it rates when I Click the td.also stores values  to localstorage.but if we just refresh html page (i tested in chrome & jsfiddle) rating are gone.values are there in localstorage. I think the errors are in retrieving data from localstorage. please check sir [ i am using 3.4.1 version of jquery)

Comment: Sorry I can't help further without example data of your json object.